# Couldn't find 'Model' with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't quite understand why this is not working. Somehow my Service ID is not getting through at all. I think i got confused with the ID's but this should work but is doesn't. When I click on submit it tells me: Couldn't find Service with 'id'=

Here's my code:

enquires_controller.rb

```
class EnquiresController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_enquire, only: [:create, :new]

  def new
    @enquire = Enquire.new
  end

  def create
    @enquire = Enquire.new(enquire_params)
    @enquire.service = @service
    if user_signed_in?
      @user = current_user
    end
    if @enquire.save
      flash[:thanks] = "Thank you"
      redirect_to service_path(@service)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def set_enquire
    @service = Service.find(params[:service_id])
  end

  def enquire_params
    params.require(:enquire).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :company, 
                                    :message, :email, :phone_number, 
                                    :service_id )
  end
```

enquire.rb

```
class Enquire < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :service
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
  validates :company, presence: true
  validates :message, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
  validates :service_id, presence: true
end
```

Service View with working @service
show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Enquire about this Service', new_enquire_path(@service), 
class: "btn btn-primary enquire-btn text-middle" %>
```

service.rb

```
has_many :enquires, :dependent => :destroy
```

routes.rb

```
resources :services do
  resources :enquires, only: [ :new, :create ]
end

resources :enquires, only: [ :new, :create, :index, :show, :destroy ]
```

and at last enquire form
_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for(@enquire) do |f| %>
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <div class="form-inputs" id="session-form">
      <%= f.input :first_name, as: "hidden", input_html: { value: @user.first_name } %>
      <%= f.input :last_name, as: "hidden", input_html: { value: @user.last_name } %>
      <%= f.input :email, as: "hidden", input_html: { value: @user.email } %>
      <%= f.input :company, as: "hidden", input_html: { value: @user.company_name } %>
      <%= f.input :phone_number, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Phone Number", label:false %>
      <%= f.input :message, autofocus: true, :input_html => { id: "no-resize" }, placeholder: "Message", label:false %>
    </div>
  <% else %>
    <div class="form-inputs" id="session-form">
      <%= f.input :first_name, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: "First Name", label:false %>
      <%= f.input :last_name, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Last Name", label:false %>
      <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Email", label:false %>
      <%= f.input :company, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Company", label:false %>
      <%= f.input :phone_number, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Phone Number", label:false %>
      <%= f.input :message, autofocus: true, :input_html => { id: "no-resize" }, placeholder: "Message", label:false %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-actions text-center">
        <%= f.button :submit, "Submit Enquiry", class: "gen-create-btn" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The params I get when clicking on submit are:

> "✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xcqR44gPOI7gsN47ddnqKxKuTcaB1Pi5goLa5H81oecbDD7nxE/A1J4KR7rY0Dbyndgz6BrFKzukkTbOCjoGMg==", "enquire"=>{"first_name"=>"daadadad", "last_name"=>"adadada", "email"=>"dadad", "company"=>"adada", "phone_number"=>"dadad", "message"=>"adada"}, "commit"=>"Submit Enquiry", "controller"=>"enquires", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>

EDIT:

Maybe the service show method has something to do with it?
services_controller.rb

```
def show
  @service = Service.find(params[:id])
  @user = current_user  
end
```

Comment: Try instead `find` with `params[:id]`: `@service = Service.find(params[:id])`, what do you get?

Comment: Still the same error message, its somehow not getting the id through at all. the service id is not in the params thats why i am so confused

Comment: What's on your `show` method?

Comment: i dont have an enquire show method for this model. and the show method for the service has nothing to do enquire either as there is only a link that should pass the id of the service i am currently viewing to the enquire form

Comment: And last but not least, have either one set of `resources` in the routes. Having multiple resources for the same will lead to confusion :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `before_action :set_enquire, only: [:create, :new]` which will get called on `new` and `create` methods.

```
def set_enquire
  @service = Service.find(params[:service_id])
end
```

When you look at the `params` that are coming to `create` method, there is no `service_id`,so `params[service_id]` is `nil`. So it fails with `Couldn't find Service with 'id'=`

**Solution:**

Remove the `before_action` for `create` method

```
before_action :set_enquire, only: [:new]
```

and as `@service` is **available** at `new` method, send the `service_id` from the form as a `hidden_field`

```
<%= f.hidden_filed :service_id, @service %>
```

And in `create` method, add the below line

```
@service = Service.find(params[:enquire][:service_id])
```

Or

Apart from `resources :enquires`, I can see you also have **nested resources** for `services` and `enquires`, so you can make use of those in the form like below

```
<%= simple_form_for [@service, @enquire] do |f| %>
```

**Note:**

Please change `set_enquire` to `set_service` as you are defining a `service` not `enquiry`

**Update:**

You should also change

```
<%= link_to 'Enquire about this Service', new_enquire_path(@service), 
class: "btn btn-primary enquire-btn text-middle" %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to 'Enquire about this Service', new_service_enquire_path(@service), 
class: "btn btn-primary enquire-btn text-middle" %>
```

So the `params` get passed correctly.

Comment: So i tried putting it in the service show.html.erb as well as in the _form file but somehow this error message will just not change. it indicates that something is wrong with the @service = Service.find(params[:service_id])

Comment: So. i did what you wrote, with both approaches but it can't load the form at all. always saying it couldn't find the id. So the problem is just the line @service = Service.find(params[:service_id]) in the before_action method. maybe to add, now my url says: http://localhost:3000/enquires/new.30. whats with that dot?

Comment: @WenqingKevinMa You should also change this `<%= link_to 'Enquire about this Service', new_enquire_path(@service), 
class: "btn btn-primary enquire-btn text-middle" %>` to `<%= link_to 'Enquire about this Service', new_service_enquire_path(@service), 
class: "btn btn-primary enquire-btn text-middle" %>`

Comment: Ok, I removed the <%= f.input :service_id, @service, as: :hidden %> from the from because it gave me an error saying too many arguments when reloading the form page. Now my url changed to http://localhost:3000/services/30/enquires/new and i can see the form which is good. But when I click on submit, it gives me: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass for line:  @service = Service.find(params[:enquiry][:service_id])

Comment: @WenqingKevinMa Don't remove it in the form. Try this `<%= f.hidden_filed :service_id, @service %>` instead of that

Comment: Ok, i changed it back, but somehow it still gives me that error: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass for line: @service = Service.find(params[:enquiry][:service_id]) BUT the service_id is now passed in the params which is a good sign. Parameters {"service_id"=>"30", "first_name"=>"dmkjgnkjdng", "last_name"=>"kgnkjngk", "email"=>"ngkngk", "company"=>"ngkun", "phone_number"=>"kuhk", "message"=>"bhkj"} permitted: false>, "commit"=>"Submit Enquiry", "controller"=>"enquires", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>

Comment: @WenqingKevinMa Can you paste the params when you click the submit?

Comment: @WenqingKevinMa Wait your model is Enquire so change it `@service = Service.find(params[:enquire][:service_id])`

Comment: OOOOOOOHHHHH, i am so silly. yes i see that!!!! it works now, thank you so much for your time. i really really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem comes from two routes for enquires resource inside your routes.rb, if your object comes from second resource :enquires it will generate an error since it cannot find "the parent" route which is service.

```
resources :services do
  resources :enquires, only: [ :new, :create ]
end

resources :enquires, only: [ :new, :create, :index, :show, :destroy ]
```

Comment: So i changed this to resources :services do
  resources :enquires, only: [ :new, :create ]
end

resources :enquires, only: [ :index, :show, :destroy ] which makes sense. If I use the answer pavan gave me i get the error: No route matches [POST] "/enquires"